# AndEngine Texture Error

Tags: android, andengine

I was following [this](http://andenginefromscratch.blogspot.com/2011/03/introduccion-andengine-parte-ii.html) tutorial and I keep getting an error. Here is the offending line of code:

```
this.mTexture = new Texture(64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

I get the error

```
Cannot instantiate the type Texture
```

Everything is imported correctly, but I keep getting the error.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guide is old. `Texture` class is abstract now, so you can not instantiate objects of it.

Use one of its subclasses - `BitmapTextureAtlas` for example.

I don't recommend you to continue with this guide, unless it gets updated. I had a short look and I saw a bit out-of-date stuff. There are many up-to-date tutorials in the [AndEngine forums](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/), you can try them out.